# Is it possible for NATS JetStream Publisher to get notification about discarded message?

Tags: nats.io, nats-jetstream

Let's say we use InterestPolicy and LimitsPolicy for NATS JetStream publisher. It means our message could be discarded in some cases (for example, when there is no consumers, or some time has been expired). In this case, sometimes it's very important for publisher to know if some message has not beed consumed. Looking at NATS documentation and code examples, I can't find such an option. The only similar thing is available for "request-reply" model (not JetStream).
So, is it really impossible for JetStream publisher to know if particular message has been discarded, or I am missing something?